# How to import Android photos to Windows?

Tags: android, photos

I want to move my photos (**move** not copy)

From:

- Galaxy S6

To:

- Windows 8.1

I've tried the following

### Dragging & Dropping

- I've tried SHIFT-dragging and dropping them, and *that copies them* but the photo first creates a 2.1GB file for a split second before each transfer (presumably because that's how much I'm transferring).
- If I try to move the photos, it WILL NOT delete them from the Android :( I don't want them stored in two places.
- It will also not properly do a merge by asking to overwrite or not if the files already exist

### Kies 3

- This fails saying it's no longer supported on my device

### SmartSwitch

- This doesn't have photo import like Kies did

Answer (score 0):

**Picasa** seems to actually do this appropriately. Unfortunately it has several attempts of trying to send the photos to google servers, so you have to disable all of that if you care about privacy.